# Implementing my own LinkedList, insertion of a new element to the Tail doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I`m trying to implement my own *linkedlist* and I tackled with this question.

This is  add method implementation for *linkedlist*, supposed to add specified elements to the end of the list.

Below you see a code I found and that works, and you see my code which only shows last `2` elements added no matter how many you add to the list.

The only difference `2` codes have is that he stores `rootNode` (*head*) inside `currentNode` and does his traversing using `currentNode`. I directly used `rootNode` to do the same. Can someone explain my what is wrong with my code ?

This is his code that works:

```
public void add (E val) {       
    Node newNode = new Node(val, null); 
    Node currentNode = rootNode;
    
    if (rootNode == null) {          
        rootNode = newNode;
    } else {                         
        while (currentNode.nextNode != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;   
        } 
        currentNode.setNextNode(newNode);
    }
}
```

And this is my code that only shows last `2` elements added :

```
public void add (E val) {       
    Node newNode = new Node(val, null);
    
    if (rootNode == null) {          
        rootNode = newNode;
    } else {                        
        while (rootNode.nextNode != null) {
            rootNode = rootNode.nextNode;   
        } 
        rootNode.setNextNode(newNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're updating the `rootNode` field in the loop. By the end it'll be pointing to the last node.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're resigning the `rootNode` while iterating.

By making this, you are erasing all previous state of the list, which you can access only via root. That's way the only node that remain in the list are root and its next node.

In order to iterate over the list, you should introduce the local variable like in the first version. There's no other way around.

And I suggest to simplify the method a bit by returning after checking whether the root is `null`, there will be no in nesting the loop into the additional block of curly braces:

```
public void add (E val) {
    Node newNode = new Node(val,null);
    
    if(rootNode == null) {
        rootNode = newNode;
        return;
    }

    Node currentNode = rootNode;
    while (rootNode.nextNode != null) {
        rootNode = rootNode.nextNode;
    } 
    rootNode.setNextNode(newNode);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see !!! thank you , I just couldn`t see this . I was thinking well , currentNode and rootNode both have the same address , but I did not think even while printing , I`m accessing the list through root and it`s getData method which returns whatever is inside ..  updating the root , I cannot even see what has been in there previously .. I guess this is going to be part of implementation of clear method , maybe haha. Thanks a lot .

Comment: @begumsakin *I was thinking well , currentNode and rootNode both have the same address* - you can introduce a local variable inside the method `Node rootNode = ...` and it will [hide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-method-hiding) the variable `rootNode` defined in the global scope (BTW it's not a good practice to do so). And it'll work, the data stored in global variable will remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing root node, after add method ends, you have only the root node and the next node of it, do not change root node if it is not null.
For instance, you call add Method for nodes A, B, and C.
For the first time root is A, then when you call add(B), as the root node is not null already, loop will not work in the else statement and the next of A will be B, then when you call add(C), while loop will work one iteration and B will become root node(you lost A) and the next of B will be C node.